# Collision detection of Physics Bodies

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have levels which load from a xml level file.
I have blocks that are added. The amount of blocks depends on the level.

What I would like to do is, if ANY of these blocks collide with each other or any other body is makes a sound.

How would I go about doing this? I have a method that loops adding the objects to the level.

Comment: It seems to me that andengine has examples of collision detection.

Comment: i know but the thing is i would like to detect collision among the same items but they are placed on the scene. I dont want to create a seperate sprite for each one and hard code the collision detection if you know what i mean. I know how to use a contact listener but having a hard time with the logic of this.

Comment: Check out [JBox2d](http://jbox2d.org/) java version of [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) Some nice demos to look at [here](http://gwtbox2d.appspot.com/) too

Comment: are you using the user data object in the physics body?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Box2D ContactListener to listen to collisions in the engine and handle them there.